# Change locale in timevis (PT)

Tags: r

Don't get the brazilian locale to work:

```
timevis(
  data.frame(id = 1:2,
             content = c("one", "two"),
             start = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-12")),
             options = list(locale = c("pt_BR"))
)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code on your head section:

```
tags$head(tags$script(src = "https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"))
```